# how to replace \n with normal line HTML newline?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Im editting an existing function wherein it gets HTML contents from a textarea and then send it to the specific receiver.

[image: sample html code]

The issue is when the receiver gets that email, table contents are misaligned. due to the existing function wherein newlines are being replaced with "\n"

is there anyway to replace the "\n" with a normal new line?

```
var content = FormatEmailString(ac, wfDataDetails, token, isApprover, detDetails, componentListBre, wfProcess, wfProcessAction).Replace("\n", "<br/>");
```

this is what i get when i debug:

```
<table border=\"1\"><tr><th align=\"center\">Leave type</th><th align=\"center\">Leave Rate</th>\n<th align=\"center\">Start Date</th>\n<th align=\"center\">End Date</th>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td align=\"center\"></td>\n<td align=\"center\"></td>\n<td align=\"center\">22/08/2019</td>\n<td align=\"center\">22/08/2019</td>\n</tr>\n</table>\n
```

As you can notice the HTML is being appended with "\n"

Comment: `\n` - is a normal newline character (it literally mean "**n**ew line"). Meanwhile `<br />` - is not a newline at all.

Comment: Html table formatting does not depend on newlines. So this is certainly not the cause of misalignment. I don't think, that _<th></th><br /><th></th>_ is valid html. Is the _align="center"_ attribute causing what you think is misalignment?